# Python's .group() returning only the first match

Tags: python, regex

I ran the following code and get only the first ')' as a match. Could someone help me with why the regular greedy '))' is not being returned?

```
r=re.compile('\)')
var=r.search('- hi- ))there')
print var.group()
```

Comment: Maybe you want `\)+`?

Answer (score 9):

[`search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search) will only return the first match.

To find all matches use [`findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall):

```
r=re.compile('\)')
var= r.findall('- hi- )) there')
print (var)
```

If you want to find both braces in one match use:

```
r=re.compile('\)+')
```

The `+` matches to 1 or more of the object.

Answer (score 5):

Your regex isn't greedy.  In fact, it's set up to match only a single character.  If you want it to match repeats as well, add a `+`:

```
>>> r=re.compile('\)+')
>>> var=r.search('- hi- ))there')
>>> print var.group()
))
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. 
findall() seemed to work for me.